# Need all in and out time based on another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I have two tables,based on intime and out time from table1  i try to  get all in and out time in table 2. Below query works fine for day working punches but for night to day output varies.

> Table 1: Daily_attendace_data

```
att_date    emp_code      in_time                   out_time
2018-10-21  9999    2018-10-21 08:00:00.000 2018-10-22 06:00:00.000
```

> Table 2: Trnevents

```
emp_reader_id          DT
9999                2018-10-21 08:00:00.000
9999                2018-10-22 06:00:00.000
```

> My query:

I am using pivot to get all punches

```
declare @tempProcesstable as table(
    [id] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [time_stamp] datetime NULL,
    [AccessType] varchar(3)  NULL) 
insert into @tempProcesstable 

        select distinct t1.emp_Reader_id, t1.DT,t1.eventid from   daily_attendance_data t2 join trnevents t1
on t1.emp_reader_id=t2.emp_reader_id where   (CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_Date, 23) >=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-20', 23) 
                       and CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), t2.att_date, 23) <=CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), '2018-10-21', 23))
                   and
                   (t1.DT >=t2.in_time 
                       and  t1.DT <=t2.out_time)
                        --   and t1.emp_reader_id=1000
                               group by t1.emp_Reader_id,t1.dt,t1.eventid order by t1.emp_reader_id,DT asc
                  ; With CheckIns
As (Select Rowemp_reader_id = Row_Number() Over (Partition by id, Cast(time_stamp As Date) Order By time_stamp),
        id, time_stamp,
        [Date] = Cast(time_stamp As Date),

        [Time] = Cast(time_stamp As Time(0))
    From @tempProcesstable)
Select Pvt.id,B.emp_name ,  [Date], CHECK1, CHECK2,Cast(dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,CHECK1,CHECK2),0) As Time(0)) Total1,
 CHECK3, CHECK4,Cast(dateadd(ss,datediff(ss,CHECK3,CHECK4),0) As Time(0)) Total2


From (Select id, [Date], [Time],
        CHECKNum = 'CHECK' + Cast(Rowemp_reader_id As varchar(11))
    From CheckIns) As P
Pivot (Min([Time])
    For CheckNum In (Check1, [Check2], Check3, Check4)
    ) As Pvt    

     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.employee AS B ON Pvt.id= B.emp_reader_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.departments AS C ON B.dept_id = C.dept_id
```

> My Output:

```
id  emp_name    Date         CHECK1   CHECK2    Total1  CHECK3  CHECK4  Total2
9999    Test    2018-10-21  08:00:00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
9999    Test    2018-10-22  06:00:00    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

> My Expected Output:

```
id       att_date     Check1    Check2    Check3    Check4
9999    2018-10-21  08:00:00    06:00:00    NULL    NULL
```

If i partition by only id it gets my expected output but not proper for all days.i stuck here,can anyone help to sort out this.

Comment: 1- You need to be a bit more specific on your sql server version because in 2012 they introduced LAG and LEAD and man, those functions are useful. 2- I remember similar questions, and having answered a [very similar one using CTE's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205873/get-all-punch-in-and-out-for-each-employee). It is probably duplicated/already answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting all punch in and punch out of an employee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395346/getting-all-punch-in-and-punch-out-of-an-employee)

Comment: s but i am trying to get all in and out in a row

Comment: That is what my answer in my first comment does. It converts a punch in/out table data into one row with two columns (in and out). You could check it, try it, and if you find it useful upvote it.

Comment: i want to get all punch in a row not only 2 column

Comment: Well, having the two columns you do the pivot. Do note that in my answer I get a counter so you can work with it and convert that data in as many columns as you need (third column counter == 3, forth counter == 4).

Comment: ok thanks @bradbury9 let me try

Comment: The answer D-shih made is what you would need, using a CTE to get the ordered punches and work from that (the group by and conditional sum he does would be perfect for your use case)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to make row number in subquery by `att_date` date, then use condition aggregate function to make it.

```
SELECT emp_readr_id,
       emp_name,
       att_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN time END) 'CHECK1',
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN time END) 'CHECK2',
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN time END) 'CHECK3',
       MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 4 THEN time END) 'CHECK4'
FROM (
   SELECT emp_readr_id,
       emp_name,
       att_date ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY att_date ORDER BY DT) rn,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DT,108) time
FROM Daily d 
JOIN Trnevents t on t.DT between d.in_time and d.out_time
) t1
group by emp_readr_id,
       emp_name,
       att_date
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5d4b9693e3264a7e2e663d770a2ab52)

**Result**

```
id       att_date     Check1    Check2    Check3    Check4
9999    2018-10-21  08:00:00    06:00:00    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Second question regarding that specific `Trnevents` table, would be nice to know what product provides that table (and why doesnt it store the data in a datetime column). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205873/get-all-punch-in-and-out-for-each-employee

Answer (score 0):

Try this query. Note that here I have created a temp table as #Base.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Base', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Base; 

CREATE table #Base
(
    emp_code INT, att_date DATE, DT DATETIME, ColName VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO #Base
SELECT X.emp_code, X.att_date, X.DT, 'Check'+CAST(X.Num AS VARCHAR(MAX))
FROM
(
  SELECT Row_Number() Over (Partition By D.emp_code, D.att_date  Order By D.emp_code, D.att_date ) As Num, *
  FROM Daily_attendace_data D
  INNER JOIN Trnevents T ON T.emp_reader_id = D.emp_code AND T.DT BETWEEN D.in_time 
  AND D.out_time
) X
ORDER BY X.DT


DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(ColName) 
                from #Base
                group by ColName, DT
                order by ColName
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


set @query = N'SELECT emp_code, att_date, ' + @cols + N' from 
         (
            select DT, ColName, emp_code, att_date
            from #Base
        ) x
        pivot 
        (
            max(DT)
            for ColName in (' + @cols + N')
        ) p '


exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: thaks for you valuable anwser . i will try an get back to you

Comment: @TimeAttendanceSystem I have done a small modification. Please check with latest query

Comment: I dislike this answer because it is overcomplicated, the CTE+group by is far more easy to mantain (and has better performance).