# how to get total no of working hours with date & time in sql server with reference to checkin & next day checkout time

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

i have this table and i want to get time_in and time_out

```
BADGENUMBER CHECKTIME   SENSORID
172 2020-06-16 19:24:49.000 1
172 2020-06-17 05:30:03.000 1
172 2020-06-17 19:41:17.000 1
172 2020-06-18 08:07:51.000 1
172 2020-06-18 19:10:57.000 1
172 2020-06-19 05:25:12.000 1
172 2020-06-20 19:06:06.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:24.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:27.000 1
172 2020-06-21 18:55:04.000 1
172 2020-06-22 06:07:48.000 1
172 2020-06-22 18:34:48.000 1
172 2020-06-23 05:00:31.000 1
172 2020-06-16 19:24:49.000 1
172 2020-06-17 05:30:03.000 1
172 2020-06-17 19:41:17.000 1
172 2020-06-18 08:07:51.000 1
172 2020-06-18 19:10:57.000 1
172 2020-06-19 05:25:12.000 1
172 2020-06-20 19:06:06.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:24.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:27.000 1
172 2020-06-21 18:55:04.000 1
172 2020-06-22 06:07:48.000 1
172 2020-06-22 18:34:48.000 1
172 2020-06-23 05:00:31.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:27.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:29.000 1
172 2020-06-16 19:24:49.000 1
172 2020-06-17 05:30:03.000 1
172 2020-06-17 19:41:17.000 1
172 2020-06-18 08:07:51.000 1
172 2020-06-18 19:10:57.000 1
172 2020-06-19 05:25:12.000 1
172 2020-06-20 19:06:06.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:24.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:27.000 1
172 2020-06-21 18:55:04.000 1
172 2020-06-22 06:07:48.000 1
172 2020-06-22 18:34:48.000 1
172 2020-06-23 05:00:31.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:27.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:29.000 1
172 2020-06-24 07:06:40.000 1
172 2020-06-24 19:01:12.000 1
172 2020-06-24 19:01:20.000 1
172 2020-06-16 19:24:49.000 1
172 2020-06-17 05:30:03.000 1
172 2020-06-17 19:41:17.000 1
172 2020-06-18 08:07:51.000 1
172 2020-06-18 19:10:57.000 1
172 2020-06-19 05:25:12.000 1
172 2020-06-20 19:06:06.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:24.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:27.000 1
172 2020-06-21 18:55:04.000 1
172 2020-06-22 06:07:48.000 1
172 2020-06-22 18:34:48.000 1
172 2020-06-23 05:00:31.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:27.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:29.000 1
172 2020-06-24 07:06:40.000 1
172 2020-06-24 19:01:12.000 1
172 2020-06-24 19:01:20.000 1
172 2020-06-25 07:03:19.000 1
172 2020-06-25 18:53:55.000 1
172 2020-06-26 05:17:45.000 1
172 2020-06-28 19:09:34.000 1
172 2020-06-29 05:00:07.000 1
172 2020-06-29 05:00:09.000 1
172 2020-06-16 19:24:49.000 1
172 2020-06-17 05:30:03.000 1
172 2020-06-17 19:41:17.000 1
172 2020-06-18 08:07:51.000 1
172 2020-06-18 19:10:57.000 1
172 2020-06-19 05:25:12.000 1
172 2020-06-20 19:06:06.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:24.000 1
172 2020-06-21 05:11:27.000 1
172 2020-06-21 18:55:04.000 1
172 2020-06-22 06:07:48.000 1
172 2020-06-22 18:34:48.000 1
172 2020-06-23 05:00:31.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:27.000 1
172 2020-06-23 18:57:29.000 1
172 2020-06-24 07:06:40.000 1
172 2020-06-24 19:01:12.000 1
172 2020-06-24 19:01:20.000 1
172 2020-06-25 07:03:19.000 1
172 2020-06-25 18:53:55.000 1
172 2020-06-26 05:17:45.000 1
172 2020-06-28 19:09:34.000 1
172 2020-06-29 05:00:07.000 1
172 2020-06-29 05:00:09.000 1
172 2020-06-29 19:08:50.000 1
172 2020-06-30 05:23:19.000 1
172 2020-06-30 18:56:33.000 1
```

i want to get the time in and out if the out time in the next day if exist

Comment: How do you determine which CHECKTIME is IN or OUT?

Comment: How do you know which line is for check_in and which for check_out?

Comment: I added the database tag.  You should provide desired results and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: i want to get the time in and out if the **out time in the next day if exist** -- Means???

Comment: This is screaming for [window functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: As others have mentioned, this is very straightforward with Window Functions, but the output of any such script will have a lot of incorrect edge cases.  Because you don't know whether someone was coming *in* or *out* at each `checktime`, you won't know if the time difference between the timestamps refers to the being in the office or out of it.

Comment: Also, why does the dataset in your question have 5 duplicates for each row?

Comment: Very similar, or duplicated, to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205873/get-all-punch-in-and-out-for-each-employee/48206258#48206258)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine "odd rows" with "even rows", you can use `row_number()`:

```
select badgenumber, min(checktime), max(checktime)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by badgenumber order by checktime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by floor( (seqnum - 1) / 2 );
```

Comment: you could also `where seqnum % 2 = 1` instead of doing the `group by`.

Comment: @bradbury9 . . . That would require an additional `lead()`.